# Perfmon quick rundown

Tags: windows, performance-monitor

I've known quite along while about performance monitor on Windows. I have decided now to create a scheduled performance monitoring of my entire system so I can find bottlenecks for future improvements. So as you can imagine this is going to run 24/7 so I can identify peak utilization.

With performance monitor on Windows 7 for example where are the logs stored (c:\perfmon)? Is there a log size?

Even better is the a website that can get me up to speed with scheduling and best practices of perfmon? (I don't need an explanation of what I can monitor)

Answer (score 1):

See this page

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744567(WS.10).aspx